# Error creating a Ruby launchd task with RVM in OS X

Tags: macos, ruby, launchd, rvm, rubygems

I want to periodically run a ruby gem based command. I am using RVM and following the tutorial set out [here](http://notes.jerzygangi.com/creating-a-ruby-launchd-task-with-rvm-in-os-x/).

My ruby task is called `daily_checks.rb` and is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts 'in here'
Dir.chdir('/Users/Chris/Documents/Sites/mentor') do
  audit = `bundle-audit`
  system(%(osascript -e 'display notification "#{audit}" with title "bundle-audit"'))
end
```

I have set up an RVM alias and a bash file at `/usr/local/bin/regular_checks.sh`

```
/Users/Chris/.rvm/wrappers/regular_checks/ruby /Users/Chris/Documents/Sites/mentor/script/daily_checks.rb
```

When I run `/usr/local/bin/regular_checks.sh` then the ruby file is executed and works successfully.

I have then setup a plist at `/Users/Chris/Library/LaunchAgents/local.temp.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PATH</key>
        <string>/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.temp</string>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/local/bin/regular_checks.sh</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/test.stderr</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/test.stdout</string>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>300</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

When I run this job using launchControl, the job appears to fail with error number 78.  The `puts 'in here'` in the ruby file is not executed.

The file permissions appear the same as in the tutorial i.e.

```
-rwxr--r--  1 Chris  staff   699 24 Nov 20:16 local.temp.plist
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Chris  admin  111 24 Nov 20:10 /usr/local/bin/regular_checks.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Chris  admin   207 25 Nov 13:38 daily_checks.rb
```

What is error 78, and why is the file not running properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the error 78 is because the `/usr/local/bin/regular_checks.sh` file does not have `#!/bin/bash` as the first line. The full content of the file should be

```
#!/bin/bash
/Users/Chris/.rvm/wrappers/regular_checks/ruby /Users/Chris/Documents/Sites/mentor/script/daily_checks.rb
```